# Quarkus: How to connect replicated SQL database with read/write instances?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, google-cloud-platform, quarkus

I want to connect a Qurkus/Hibernate-based application to [a replicated PostgreSQL instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication) running in Google Cloud. Such a replication assumes **there is a write instance** and **there are several read replicas**.

I went through [the Qurkus documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource) but couldn't find a way to do it. There is a way to setup multiple data sources for different databases, but it is not what I need.

**Question:** How to configure read/write DB instances in Quarkus?

I am using `Quarkus 1.11.3.Final`.

Answer (score 2):

I haven’t tried using cloud SQL but reading the docs you would want to explore how jdbc is configured.

So try follow https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/main/docs/jdbc-postgres.md and use that with Quarkus. See https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource on how to configure jdbc.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion (+1). I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a guide for Cloud SQL, it's not yet finised as there is some issue with dev mode that we want to handle before adding the guide.

So, you need to add the Cloud SQL JDBC socket lib.

Then configure the socket factory of PostreSQL via the additional JDBC properties:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=other
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql:///mydabatabe
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
quarkus.datasource.username=quarkus
quarkus.datasource.password=quarkus
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.additional-jdbc-properties.cloudSqlInstance=project-id:gcp-region:instance
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.additional-jdbc-properties.socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory
```

Everything is explained here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/15783/files#diff-a52617b3eb5153201582a0aa218aca7bded4e1712c3566c8f052737139c716c9R221

As I said, this will not work in dev mode so you must use a local database for using dev mode.

Please provides feedback if it didn't work for you

Comment: Thank you, it connects well. However all queries hit only the master node. Any ideas how to make it see the replicated instances?

Comment: @SashaShpota this question should be ask on Google Cloud Side, I'm not sure it's even possible. The way you connect to Cloud SQL is the correct one so I assume this is the attended behaviour.

Comment: I check on the Cloud SQL documentation and Cloud SQL is a hot standby it means all queries goes to the primary node, when the primary is down, the standaby node will be promoted to primary and will takes the request.